# Appium findElement used twice in one row not working

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, appium

I am trying to find an element by its full path (wholeElement) and by first finding the higher level element and then finding the lower level element within that element (modularElement).  Here is my code:

```
    WebElement modularElement = appDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//UIATableCell[2]")).findElement(By.xpath("//UIAStaticText[4]"));
    WebElement wholeElement = appDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//UIATableCell[2]/UIAStaticText[4]"));

    Logger.LogMessage("modularElement attribute1: " + modularElement.getLocation(), Priority.High);
    Logger.LogMessage("wholeElement attribute1: " + wholeElement.getLocation(), Priority.High);
```

The really strange issue I am experiencing is the two elements (modular and whole) are different elements and not the same one (shown by the different locations printed in the code above).  Can anyone explain why this is the case?

Thanks.

UPDATE:

I have also tried using .// but that is providing the same issue still:

```
    WebElement modularElement = appDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//UIATableCell[2]")).findElement(By.xpath(".//UIAStaticText[4]"));
```

Answer (score 8):

They are not the same.

```
appDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//UIATableCell[2]")).findElement(By.xpath("//UIAStaticText[4]"));
```

Here, you are searching for `//UIAStaticText[4]` anywhere, [*at any level* in the entire DOM tree](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html):

> When using xpath be aware that webdriver follows standard conventions:
>   a search prefixed with "//" will search the entire document, not just
>   the children of this current node. Use ".//" to limit your search to
>   the children of this WebElement.

While `//UIATableCell[2]/UIAStaticText[4]` would search *among the direct children* of `//UIATableCell[2]` only.

Comment: Are you sure that the first line of code would find `UIAStaticText` only under  `UIATableCell[2]`, and not anywhere else in the document? Just asking, since an XPath starting with `//` normally selects from all descendants of the *root node of the document*. (I agree with your general statement about the difference between `/` and `//`, though.)

Comment: @LarsH that's a great point! I've missed that. Edited. Many thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  Afraid using ./UIAStaticText[4] is resulting in an 'element could not be located' error.  Copied and pasted the 2 lines of code above and the wholeElement is being found but the modularElement is not.

Comment: Also tried .//UIAStaticText[4] (double forward slash) but that gave the same result as using //UIAStaticText[4] (i.e. without the full stop before the double forward slashes)

Comment: @CharlieSeligman thanks for trying it out. Now I see my error. The expressions at the end of the answer are still not the same. `wholeElement` has a match because there is a `UIAStaticText[4]` element *among all* `UIATableCell[2]` found in the DOM. But, in the first expression  it would pick up *the first* `appDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//UIATableCell[2]"))` match and would try to find `./UIAStaticText[4]` inside. I may not be explaining it well, but I hope you've got what my mistake was. Thanks.

Comment: @Alecxe - thanks for the info.  I see what you mean.  So the first UIATableCell[2] that appium finds might not have any UIAStaticText inside it.   However, in this case there is only one instance of UIATableCell[2] on the DOM, so it cant be that Im afraid.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like so instead:

```
By locator = new ByChained(By.xpath("//UIATableCell[2]"),By.xpath(".//UIAStaticText[4]")); 
WebElement modularElement = appDriver.findElement(locator);
```

Or perhaps this:

```
public WebElement getCellTextElement(int cell, String varText) {
  By locator = new ByChained(By.xpath("//UIATableCell[" + cell + "]"),
      By.xpath(".//UIAStaticText[contains(text(),'" + varText + "')]")); 
  WebElement modularElement = appDriver.findElement(locator);
  return modularElement;
}
```